# iOS App crashes on exit

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access, destructor, objective-c++

I'm having an issue where my iOS App is crashing on exit and I've narrowed it down to this:

```
// File.h

struct Name {
    NSString *name;
}

// File.mm

Name names[] = {
    @"foo",
    @"bar",
};
```

When the App exits (pushing the home button on the iPad), I get a crash in `objc_msgSend` with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)`.  It's happening the the destructor `Name::~Name()`.

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib         0x37586e3a objc_release + 10
1   MyApp                   0x0014abfc Name::~Name() (NameManager.h:21)
2   MyApp                   0x0014ab42 Name::~Name() (NameManager.h:21)
3   MyApp                   0x0014ad94 __cxx_global_array_dtor + 120
4  libsystem_c.dylib        0x36bba1cc __cxa_finalize + 216
5  libsystem_c.dylib        0x36b854f6 exit + 6
```

Keep in mind that this is in a .mm file, so it's being compiled as obj-c++.

This has worked fine for months and months.  I don't know exactly when it started happening, but I suspect it was when I updated to xcode 4.4.

`NSString` literals should be protected (or always have been) against multiple releases, but I don't think that is happening here anyway.

Does anyone know if something changed in xcode 4.4?

I can fix the crash by doing:

```
struct Name {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *name;
}
```

But I hate to do that without understanding why what has worked before no longer works.  Or maybe it never should have worked.  I also fear a memory over-write, so this might just be a symptom.

This happens in both DEBUG and RELEASE.

UPDATE: I put a breakpoint in ~Name() and verified that memory is not corrupt. LLDB is able to dump the NSString OK.  But it crashes when I step.

Comment: No, I've been under ARC for quite a while.

Comment: I don't have any suggestions but the stack trace strikes me as odd.  Is it saying that the `Name` destructor is calling itself (frames 1 and 2)?

Comment: @Phillip Mills don't mind that - that's how LLDB shows the stack trace (I also wonder why...)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a "Plain Old Data" `struct` in Objective-C++ that contains Objective-C objects with ARC turned on, the compiler is obligated to provide a destructor that correctly deallocates the ObjC members of the struct, even if you do not write them yourself.

> This restriction does not apply in Objective-C++. However, nontrivally
>   ownership-qualified types are considered non-POD: in C++11 terms, they
>   are not trivially default constructible, copy constructible, move
>   constructible, copy assignable, move assignable, or destructible. It
>   is a violation of C++’s One Definition Rule to use a class outside of
>   ARC that, under ARC, would have a nontrivially ownership-qualified
>   member.

When you declared that Name structure, the compiler would have written you a destructor involving an implicit strongly held Objective-C object.  At execution time, what this means is that the C++ destructor erases what it expects is a C++ structure and instead winds up borking the pointers to the string.  With no valid pointer around, the `-release` ARC tries to send segfaults when it tries to dereference a nonexistent receiver.

When you declare an Objective-C member `__unsafe_unretained`, it tells ARC to exclude it from the destructor it would have to write, thus the struct is just destroyed, and the `-release` is never sent.  It is recommended that you mark all Objective-C objects in structures or classes as `__unsafe_unretained` and provide the appropriate memory management yourself,  because ARC can significantly complicate object lifetimes across languages.

Comment: "and instead winds up borking the pointers to the string. With no valid pointer around, the -release ARC tries to send segfaults when it tries to dereference a nonexistent receiver." Why would it be nonexistent? Since it's a strong reference, it should keep the object alive.